# Flat File import with single column is being truncated below the data size available

Tags: ssis

I have a very simple SSIS package that imports one column from a flat file as a Text Stream [DT_TEXT] for each row. I then have an OLE DB Destination (I've also tried ADO NET) that inserts this into my staging table.

It seems to work fine but only 43,680 characters are being imported, both the source and destination are Text Datatypes so 2,147,483,647 characters should be available.

I can't understand where this truncation is coming from, if anyone can help it's driving me crazy, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Flat File connection manager sets the length of string columns to 50 characters(OutputColumnWidth of 50). In the Flat File Connection Manager Editor dialog box, you can evaluate sample data and automatically resize the length of these columns to prevent truncation of data or excess column width.

[MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017#column-length)

[Remap column data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-2-adding-and-configuring-a-flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017#remap-column-data-types)

Comment: I don't think this is the real cause since the OP mentioned that `43,680 characters are being imported`

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with DT_TEXT but more related to how SSMS limits the display of characters. If you use LEN([YourColumn]), you may see your data is actually stored in your destination completely, but SSMS just doesn't show the full set of characters when you query it by SELECT. You can go to Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid to extend it to 65535, so you may see more characters.
Following thread has more details.
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/varcharmax-not-storing-all-data